# Using a PHP form, get the page title or any other element in the sent e-mail

Tags: php, forms

I am using a PHP form which I add in a page as a shortcode. I would like the user that receives the e-mail to also receive some indicator of the page the form was in...Is it possible to somehow get the value of anything in the page where the shortcode is placed?

This is the form's send email function which generates the email content:

```
function send_email() {

    // generate content
    $content = "From: ".$_POST['mk-name']."\r\nEmail: ".$_POST['mk-email'];

    if(!empty($_POST['mk-company'])) {
        $content .= "\r\nCompany: ".$_POST['mk-company'];
    }

    $content .= "\r\n\r\n".$_POST['mk-message'];

    // generate headers
    $headers = 'From: '.$_POST['mk-name'].' <'.$this->from.'>'."\r\nReply-To: " . $_POST['mk-email']."\r\n";

    if(!empty($this->atts['cc'])) {
        $headers .= 'Cc: '.$this->atts['cc']."\r\n";
    }
    if(!empty($this->atts['bcc'])) {
        $headers .= 'Bcc: '.$this->atts['bcc']."\r\n";
    }

    // send email
    wp_mail($this->to, $this->subject, $content, $headers);

}
```

Comment: Has this function been trimmed down? There are references to variables that are never defined, and `$this` but this isn't a class method, it's a function. Additionally it's not clear how the shortcode is implemented or the form is handled. Is there a reason this was implemented as a shortcode?

Comment: Sure yes, the file is pretty big and there's things that I cannot include here. It is implemented as a shortcode because it's kind of like a starter theme pack where the folder structure should be kept as it is.